# Abscissa of Convergence (and of Absolute Convergence) of the Derivative of a Dirichlet Series

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Given the series:

$$F(s) = \sum f(n) n^{-s}$$

with abscissa of convergence $\sigma_c$. It's derivative would be:

$$F'(s) = - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{f(n) \log(n)}{n^s}$$

Aopstol, "Intro to Analytic NT" p.236, says the derivative series has the same abscissas of convergence and of absolute convergence as the original series, $F(s)$.

Since the original series is analytic in the half-plane of convergence $\sigma > \sigma_c$, this makes sense.

I was wondering how to show it explicitly for the given series. I have tried assuming every term of the original series is bounded in that half-plane but that only leads to $M \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \log(n)$.

Also I can show by the integral test (just for an initial attempt) that
$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n^s}$ converges.

But in truth, I am stuck. I would appreciate help as to how to show it explicitly and especially that $\sigma > \sigma_c$ is still adequate to take care of the additional $\log (n)$ factor of each term in the derivative series.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi Andrew.  Are you asking to justify the abscissa of absolute convergence for the example $\zeta'(s)$, or are  you asking for a proof of Apostol's more general assertion that $F$ and $F'$ have the same abscissa of convergence?

Comment: @JohnM Preferably the more general case would be appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Apostol's Theorem 11.11 to $|f(n)|$ rather than $f(n)$ to get that the partial sums $$\sum_{n=1}^N |f(n)| n^{-s}$$ converge uniformly on compact subsets lying in the open half-plane to the right of $\sigma_c$.  Then apply Lemma 3 (pg. 234) to get that the derivatives $$-\sum_{n=1}^N |f(n)| \log(n) n^{-s}$$ also converge uniformly on compact subsets to the right of $\sigma_c$.

In particular, we get the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^N |f(n)| \log(n) n^{-\Re{s}}$$ when $\Re{s} > \sigma_c.$
This is exactly equivalent to the absolute convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \log(n) n^{-s}$$ for $\Re{s} > \sigma_c.$

**2nd (and better!) method requested by Andrew**

Let $\sigma$ be greater than $\sigma_c$.  Choose $\sigma_2$ such that $\sigma_c < \sigma_2 < \sigma$.  Then $\sigma_2$ is in the region of absolute convergence of $F$, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|f(n)|}{n^{\sigma_2}} < \infty.$$
Now let $\epsilon > 0$.  No matter how small $\epsilon$ is, for sufficiently large $n$ we have that $n^\epsilon > \log(n)$.  Thus,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|f(n)|}{n^{\sigma_2}} \frac{\log(n)}{n^\epsilon} < \infty.$$
In particular, for $\epsilon = \sigma - \sigma_2$, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|f(n)|\log(n)}{n^{\sigma}} < \infty.$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)\log(n)}{n^{s}}$$
converges absolutely for any $s$ with $\Re{s} > \sigma_c$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it's possible to "manipulate" the series for $F'(s)$ to get some sort of comparison test where you can then claim that since the series itself for $F(x)$ converges for $\sigma > \sigma_c$ that the series itself for $F'(x)$ likewise converges? I.e., without relying on any theorems or lemmas.

Comment: @Andrew Actually yes.  Let me ammend my answer to include that too.  It will look similar to the other answer.

Comment: The cited Lemma 3 does not eliminate the possibility that the abscissa of convergence of $F'(s)$ is less than $\sigma_c.$

Comment: @user64494: Since $|f(n)| \log{n} > |f(n)|$ for $n>2$, we know that the abscissa can't be less than $\sigma_c$.  Anyway, I thought I'd add another proof to supplement yours since I wasn't sure that the Encyclopedia of Mathematics included an actual proof, which I guess the OP might want to see.

Comment: John M: You did not prove the formula from Encyclopedia of Mathematics in your answer. Its proof takes  half a page.

Comment: @user64494 - That's true.  The EoM result is interesting, but more than needed to answer Andrew's question.  Best regards.

Comment: @JohnM Thanks for making the extra effort.

Answer (score 2):

Up to [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dirichlet_series), the abscissa of the absolute convergence of a Diriclet series 
$$A=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac {\log |a_n|} {\lambda_n}.$$ In your case for $F'(s)$ $a_n= - f(n)\log(n) $ and $\lambda_n=- \log (n).$ Therefore, $$ A= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\log|f(n)\log(n)|} {-\log (n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\log|f(n)|} { -\log (n)}+\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\log|\log(n)|} {- \log (n)}=\sigma_c+0=\sigma_c$$ in your notation.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer, which I'm sure you know I upvoted immediately.